# How to pass variable from one node.js script to other

Tags: node.js, asynccallback

Is it possible that I pass a variable from one node.js script to other? So my childproccess can work in rhe background?

I have a code:

test.js

```
var myName = "Anna";
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('node', ['beta.js'],[myName], {
    detached: true
});
```

beta.js

```
const args =  process.argv[2];
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test.txt", args, function() {    
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Im getting of course undefined in my text file if I run node test.js :(

Comment: I would recommend you can take a look at this package: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc).
Also, if you're using only nodejs scripts you can use the cluster module [link] (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to spwan workers
If you still want to use 'spawn' - you can simple pass arguments to the script you're running and process them on the receiving script using this module: [link] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to pass some arguments to a spawned process, you're only passing them in the wrong way. You should pass them as the second arguments to [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

```
var myName = "Anna";
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('node', ['beta.js', myName], {
    detached: true
});
```